# error compiling openCTM in x64

Tags: c++, 64-bit, msvc12

I'm trying to compile openCTM using VC12 in x64.
OpenCTM is downloaded from: [openctm-1.0.3-src.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openctm/files/OpenCTM-1.0.3/OpenCTM-1.0.3-src.zip/download)

In order to compile, I run: nmake /f Makefile.msvc

To setup the environment I use the following bat file:

```
@rem Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio x86/x64 tools.
@echo off

@if "%1"=="vc11_x86" goto set_vc11_x86
@if "%1"=="vc11_x64" goto set_vc11_x64
@if "%1"=="vc12_x64" goto set_vc12_x64
@if "%1"=="" goto error

:set_vc11_x86
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2011 x86 tools.

set INCLUDE=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\WinRT;

set LIB=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x86\;


set PATH=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;^
%SystemRoot%\system32;^
%SystemRoot%;^
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;^
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;^
C:\MinGW\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;^
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\;

goto test_bin_locations

:set_vc11_x64
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2011 x64 tools.

set INCLUDE=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\WinRT;

set LIB=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x86\;

set PATH=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;^
%SystemRoot%\system32;^
%SystemRoot%;^
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;^
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;^
C:\MinGW\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;^
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;

goto test_bin_locations

:set_vc12_x64
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 x64 tools.

set INCLUDE=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\WinRT;

set LIB=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x86\;

set PATH=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;^
%SystemRoot%\system32;^
%SystemRoot%;^
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;^
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;^
C:\MinGW\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;^
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;

goto test_bin_locations

:test_bin_locations
@echo on
where nmake
where cl.exe
where link.exe
@echo off
goto:eof

:error
@echo Usage: setenv.bat [vc11_x86^|vc11_x64^|vc12_x64]

goto:eof
```

Compiling generates the openctm.dll when I use the vc11_x86 environment.

But it fails when using the vc11_x64 or vc12_x64 environment.

vc12_x64 main error:

```
        link /MACHINE:X64 /nologo /out:openctm.dll /dll /implib:openctm.lib /def
:openctm-msvc.def openctm.obj  stream.obj  compressRAW.obj  compressMG1.obj  com
pressMG2.obj Alloc.obj  LzFind.obj  LzmaDec.obj  LzmaEnc.obj  LzmaLib.obj openct
m.res
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
```

vc11_x86 main error:

```
Alloc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
openctm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol free referenced in funct
ion ctmFreeContext
stream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
compressMG1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
compressMG2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
Alloc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
openctm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol malloc referenced in fun
ction ctmNewContext
```

Please point me in the right direction on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found the issues:

1. I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows. Installing Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop solved the vc12_x64 issue
2. There was an reference to x86 libraries in the setenv.bat file. The correct file is:

> 

```
@rem Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio x86/x64 tools.
@echo off

@if "%1"=="vc11_x86" goto set_vc11_x86
@if "%1"=="vc11_x64" goto set_vc11_x64
@if "%1"=="vc12_x64" goto set_vc12_x64
@if "%1"=="" goto error

:set_vc11_x86
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2011 x86 tools.

set INCLUDE=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\WinRT;

set LIB=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x86\;


set PATH=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;^
%SystemRoot%\system32;^
%SystemRoot%;^
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;^
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;^
C:\MinGW\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;^
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\;

goto test_bin_locations

:set_vc11_x64
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2011 x64 tools.

set INCLUDE=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\WinRT;

set LIB=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x64\;

set PATH=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;^
%SystemRoot%\system32;^
%SystemRoot%;^
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;^
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;^
C:\MinGW\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;^
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;

goto test_bin_locations

:set_vc12_x64
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 x64 tools.

set INCLUDE=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\WinRT;

set LIB=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x64\;

set PATH=^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;^
%SystemRoot%\system32;^
%SystemRoot%;^
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;^
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;^
C:\MinGW\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;^
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;^
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64;

goto test_bin_locations

:test_bin_locations
@echo on
where nmake
where cl.exe
where link.exe
@echo off
goto:eof

:error
@echo Usage: setenv.bat [vc11_x86^|vc11_x64^|vc12_x64]

goto:eof
```